# Better was of multiple delete in a for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to delete records from multiple tables in a FOR LOOP after bulk collect. But for 6-7 tables I am writing 6-7 delete statements inside the FOR LOOP. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: 6-7 times [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB).

Comment: You will get better answers for your problem if you give us more details of the problem. Please [edit] your question and give us a [MRE] with: your tables; some sample data; the issue you are trying to solve; and your current solution. Without that we are making up our own examples or giving high-level, non-specific statements that may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Write one delete for each table but don't use the `FOR LOOP`.

For a contrived example, if you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE table2 ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, parent_id NUMBER );
CREATE TABLE table3 ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, parent_id NUMBER );
CREATE TABLE table4 ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, parent_id NUMBER );
```

and the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 ( id )
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO table2 ( id, parent_id )
SELECT id + 0.1, id FROM table1 UNION ALL
SELECT id + 0.2, id FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table3 ( id, parent_id )
SELECT id + 0.01, id FROM table2 UNION ALL
SELECT id + 0.02, id FROM table2;

INSERT INTO table4 ( id, parent_id )
SELECT id + 0.001, id FROM table3 UNION ALL
SELECT id + 0.002, id FROM table3;
```

and you want to delete `3.112` and `2.121` from `table4` and then all the parent rows from the other tables. Then you can use:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

```sql
DECLARE
  p_to_delete  number_list;
  p_to_delete2 number_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
  BULK COLLECT INTO p_to_delete
  FROM   table4
  WHERE  id IN ( 3.112, 2.121 );
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 4: ' || p_to_delete.COUNT || ' rows to be deleted.' );

  DELETE FROM table4
  WHERE  id MEMBER OF p_to_delete
  RETURNING parent_id BULK COLLECT INTO p_to_delete2;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 4: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.' );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 3: ' || p_to_delete2.COUNT || ' rows to be deleted.' );

  DELETE FROM table3
  WHERE  id MEMBER OF p_to_delete2
  RETURNING parent_id BULK COLLECT INTO p_to_delete;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 3: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.' );
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 2: ' || p_to_delete.COUNT || ' rows to be deleted.' );

  DELETE FROM table2
  WHERE  id MEMBER OF p_to_delete
  RETURNING parent_id BULK COLLECT INTO p_to_delete2;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 2: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.' );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 1: ' || p_to_delete2.COUNT || ' rows to be deleted.' );

  DELETE FROM table1
  WHERE  id MEMBER OF p_to_delete2;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Table 1: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.' );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Table 4: 2 rows to be deleted.
> Table 4: 2 rows deleted.
> Table 3: 2 rows to be deleted.
> Table 3: 2 rows deleted.
> Table 2: 2 rows to be deleted.
> Table 2: 2 rows deleted.
> Table 1: 2 rows to be deleted.
> Table 1: 2 rows deleted.
> ```

There is no `FOR ... LOOP` and multiple rows are deleted at each step.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14926a58569865f7d77d6c2c088150f3)*

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL reads "Oracle". A it doesn't allow you to delete multiple tables in one `DELETE` statement, I presume that what you currently have is how it is to be done: table-by-table.